# Using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a one page simple application with register form and log in form.
I used this function to switch between different "div" tags:

```
function replaceContentInContainer(target, source) 
    {           
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = document.getElementById(source).innerHTML;


    }
```

for some reason it doesnt work when I apply it on this following div's:

```
<div id="gameOptions" class="contentBox" hidden >
            <div class="innerBox" >
                <P>
                    <STRONG>Number of balls:</STRONG> 
                    <SELECT id="number_of_balls">
                        <OPTION>50 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>60 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>70 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>80 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>90 </OPTION>
                    </SELECT>
                </P>
                <P>
                    <STRONG>Number of ghosts:</STRONG> 
                    <SELECT id="number_of_ghosts">
                        <OPTION>3 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>2 </OPTION>
                        <OPTION>1 </OPTION>     
                    </SELECT>
                </P>
                <p>
                    <h4 style="display:inline;color:#000000;">High score food:</h4>
                    <input id="highScore_color" type="color" value="#F50905" />
                    <h4 style="display:inline;color:#000000;margin-left:15px;">Medium score food:</h4>
                    <input id="mediumScore_color" type="color" value="#03FCFC"/> 
                    <h4 style="display:inline;color:#000000;margin-left:15px">Low score food:</h4>
                    <input id="lowScore_color" type="color" value="#ffffff"/>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div><!--game options-->
```

and:

```
  <div id="reg_screen" class="contentBox" hidden>
            <div class="innerBox" >
                <form id="register_form" onsubmit="checkSubmit()" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on" >
                <br/>
                    <P style="margin:10px 0px 0px 192px;"><STRONG><span id="un_span" style="color:#D70000; visibility:hidden">*</span>User-Name: </STRONG>
                    <INPUT id="username_entred" TYPE = "text" SIZE = "25" ></P>
                    <br/>
                    <P style="margin:10px 0px 0px 205px;" ><STRONG><span id="pw_span" style="color:#D70000 ; visibility:hidden">*</span>Password:</STRONG> 
                    <INPUT id="pw_entered" TYPE = "password" SIZE = "25" ></P>
                    <br/>
                    <P style="margin:10px 0px 0px 230px;" ><STRONG><span id="name_span" style="color:#D70000; visibility:hidden">*</span>Name:</STRONG> 
                    <INPUT id="private_name"  TYPE = "text" SIZE = "25" ></P>
                    <br/>
                    <P style="margin:10px 0px 0px 200px;" ><STRONG><span id="lastName_span" style="color:#D70000 ; visibility:hidden">*</span>LastName:</STRONG> 
                    <INPUT id="last_name"  TYPE = "text" SIZE = "25" ></P>
                    <br/>
                    <P style="margin:10px 0px 0px 200px;" ><STRONG><span id="date_span" style="color:#D70000;  visibility:hidden">*</span>Birth Date:</STRONG> 
                    <INPUT id="birth_date"  TYPE = "date" width = "100px" ></P>
                    <br/>
                    <P style="text-align:center">
                    <input type="submit"  class="button" value="Sign-In" > </input></P>                                                 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Register Screen -->
```

this how I use the function:

```
replaceContentInContainer('reg_screen','gameOptions');
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: None =\, I tried debbuging it, I dont get any errors

Comment: The div id `reg_screen` doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I din't copy the right one:

Comment: Nice catch @KyleNeedham hey provide us fiddle man

Comment: I do not see you using jQuery, and have removed the irrelevant tag.

Comment: edited the correct div

Comment: When do you call the function? You need to do it only when the divs have been created so use `window.onload = function(){  code here };`

Comment: @MrCode I use it after the window was loaded, I have a basic screen with two buttons "sign-in" and "register", after I click the sign-in , the previous "div" disappears and the dic with the id "reg_screen" appears, and after I try switching between the reg_screen and the gameOptions it doesn't work

Comment: Can't replicate the problem it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/CP4n7/

Comment: _After you try switching_? Dude, how can you expect them to switch after you basicly made them equal? All you have to do is hide the one which you dont want it to be seen

Comment: The [HTML5 `hidden` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) indicates that the element *should not be rendered*. This may have to do with your problem.

Comment: @PointedEars you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @NextGenPOS In which user agent have you observed this behavior? Where are you calling the function?

Comment: @PointedEars thank you! I just used this 2 line:  document.getElementById('login').hidden = true;
document.getElementById('game').hidden = false; Thanks everyone for helping! =)

Comment: I am glad that my educated guess helped (although I do not know why yet). As requested, I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm your observations in my browsers.  However, [the HTML5 `hidden` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) indicates that the element *should not be rendered*. This may have to do with your problem.